# how to give focusing css effect in input tag

Tags: reactjs

I'm using styled-components, react, typescript.

I have two input fields, and want them to have `box-shadow` effect only when each of them are focused.

My idea is give them a state  `focus` and shows box-shadow when `focus` is `true`, but I have no idea how to implement this.

```
 const StyledInput = styled.input<{ focus: boolean}>`
  ${ p => p.focus ? `box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgb(244,231,123);` : ''}
 ` 
 const Form = () => {
   const [focus, setFocus ] = useState(false);
   // don't know how to use this state, 
   // may be focus state is not just boolean but object I guess ? 
   const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
   useEffect(() => {
     
   },[]) 
   return(
    <StyledInput 
      focus={focus}
    />
    <StyledInput 
      focus={focus}
    />
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I understand is correct, you can implement it using CSS.

```js
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgb(244,231,123);
  }
`

const Form = () => {
  return(<StyledInput />)
}
```

Comment: I see  just simply  using css focus might be better than combination of  useState and css together. good point.